# Backing up server before upgrading PHP

Tags: ubuntu, php

What's the easiest way to back up my server so in the event we run into issues during our PHP 5.3 upgrade we can revert back to PHP 5.2?

**update**

I guess a better question is, do I NEED a backup of our original setup, or is PHP plug'n play enough that I can just remove 5.3 and revert to 5.2 if it fails for whatever reason.

Comment: Totally depends on how you installed it in the first place.

Comment: Absent any other information, shut the system down and take a binary image of the hard drive with Ghost or something similar.

Comment: We need a lot more information. This question is tagged "ubuntu", but if you are upgrading your PHP version, I assume you aren't using the packaged PHP. Are you using the packaged Apache? Also, it's good practice to have a backup/restore plan in place no matter what.

Comment: I have no idea if I'm using the packaged apache/php... does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

We could use some more information.

However, I can only assume you are concerned about this upgrade because you have an application on there that you think could break in some unexpected way.  In which case I have to wonder why you have not set up a vm and tried this application there as a test.

Next, I also have to wonder how you are backing up your server in the first place, and why you don't already have a DR solution thought through.

Barring that, you can do as others have suggested and clone the machine, using Ghost or similar depending on what Operating System you are using.

Really though, there is **zero** penalty for failure in a test scenario, I don't understand why you haven't started there.

There are other ways out of this jam, but they all require you tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

`rdiff-backup` seems to be quite easy backup tool, I also recommend using `etckeeper` for tracking config file changes in `/etc`